# React/FetchAPI: How to take data from related json by id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to take data from JSON, next take another data from related JSON by ID and push it to my state array `movies`.

This is my code:

```
state = {
    movies: []
}

componentDidMount() {

    fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=APIKEY&page=1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const movies = data.results;

            movies.forEach(movie => this.moviePageAndGenres(movie.id, movie));

            this.setState({
                movies
            });
        })
}

moviePageAndGenres = (id, element) => {
    fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '?api_key=APIKEY')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            element.genres = data.genres;
            element.homepage = data.homepage;
        });
}
```

In `render()` I just `console.log` my `movies` to check if data inside is correct.

Output: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27NcR.png)

So it's correct but when I check Component Props these props are not transferred.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbdAj.png)

This is how I transfer props:

```
const movies = this.state.movies.map(movie =>
 <Movie genres={movie.genres}
        homepage={movie.homepage}
        key={movie.id}
        title={movie.title}
        poster={movie.poster_path}
        rating={movie.vote_average}
 />
)
```

I guess it's problem with multiple call of asynchronous`fetch()`. But i don't know how to handle with it.

Comment: please hide your api key

Comment: this.setState will not wait for your moviePageAndGenres  to respond.

Comment: you can try to use async functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason its not working is, you are firing multiple fetch calls which are async and setting the state immediately after it. `setState` will get empty movies in that case.

`fetch` api returns a promise and you should set your state in promise resolution handler. Modify your `componentDidMount` like this.

```
componentDidMount() {

  fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=APIKEY&page=1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          const movies = data.results;
          Promise.all(movies.map(movie => fetch(
            `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movie.id}?api_key=APIKEY`
          )))
          .then(resp => Promise.all( resp.map(r => r.json()) ))
          .then(result => {
            const movies = result.map((data, i) => {
              const movie = Object.assign(movies[i], {
                genres: data.genres,
                homepage: data.homepage
              });
              return movie;
            });
            this.setState({
              movies
            });
          });
      })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need async await in this case and it’s good to use Promise.all because you are doing fetch in forEach.

For forEach you need await Promise.all and for fetch you need await. Which mean it will wait until the forEach is completed

Change

```
    fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=APIKEY&page=1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const movies = data.results;

        movies.forEach(movie => this.moviePageAndGenres(movie.id, movie));

        this.setState({
            movies
        });
    })
```

To

```
  fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=APIKEY&page=1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(async data => {
        const movies = data.results;
        await Promise.all(movies.forEach(async movie => await this.moviePageAndGenres(movie.id, movie)))

        this.setState({
            movies
        });
    })
```

Also

Change

```
  moviePageAndGenres = (id, element) => {
      fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '?api_key=APIKEY')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        element.genres = data.genres;
        element.homepage = data.homepage;
    });
 }
```

To

```
   moviePageAndGenres = async (id, element) => {
      return await fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '?api_key=APIKEY')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        element.genres = data.genres;
        element.homepage = data.homepage;
    });
 }
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, I think OP might also need to modify `moviePageAndGenres()` so that it return a promise (simply by returning `fetch(...)`)

Comment: Yes you are right. I have updated my answer please let me know if that’s the right approach

Comment: Sorry, i was on mobile so my finger slips — please disregard the last (removed) comment!